# Unable to Update DateTime value for Start and End of IEvent Office 365

Tags: office365, adal, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I am using Office 365 V2 DLL and tryign to update DateTime value for Start and End properties of IEvent but it fails to update the event without any error.

My code :-

```
        try
        {
            var taskUpdateMeeting = Task<bool>.Run(async () =>
            {
                bool updateStatus = false;
                IEvent meetingToUpdate = await service.Me.Events.GetById(meetingEventId).ExecuteAsync();
                if (meetingToUpdate != null)
                {    
                    meetingToUpdate = GetUpdatedEvent(meetingToUpdate, meeting, location, phone);    // Function to update the IEvent Obj values needed to update
                    meetingToUpdate.Start.DateTime = "2016-08-06T19:00:00.0000000";        // Sample value to DateTime property
                    meetingToUpdate.End.DateTime = "2016-08-06T19:30:00.0000000";
                    meetingToUpdate.Start.TimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";        // Sample value to TimeZone property
                    meetingToUpdate.End.TimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";

                    if (invitees != null && invitees.Count > 0)
                        invitees.ForEach((invitee) => meetingToUpdate.Attendees.Add(new Attendee()
                        {
                            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress()
                            {
                                Name = invitee.Name,
                                Address = invitee.Email
                            },
                            Status = new ResponseStatus()
                            {
                                Response = ResponseType.Accepted,
                                Time = DateTime.Now
                            }
                        }));
                    await meetingToUpdate.UpdateAsync(true);
                    await meetingToUpdate.SaveChangesAsync();
                    //await meetingToUpdate.SaveChangesAsync();
                    //await service.Context.SaveChangesAsync();


                    updateStatus = true;
                }
                return updateStatus;
            });
            Task.WaitAll(taskUpdateMeeting);
            updated = taskUpdateMeeting.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            InsertExceptionLog(userID, username, "UpdateCalendarEvent Excp -> " + ex.GetType(), ex.Message, ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : null, ex.ToString() + ex.StackTrace);
            updated = false;
        }
```

The only problem is with the start and end time. All other properties are updating correctly when UpdateAsync method called.
Initially the meeting is in same timezone as in updated TimeZone property.
Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong here. Let me know if any other information required.

Comment: I recommend getting Fiddler installed and capture the API requests over the wire. This is usually the most useful thing for me when troubleshooting the API.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set the date and time zone directly, we can set the **Start** and **End** property. The sample below works well for me:

```
DateTimeTimeZone newStart = new DateTimeTimeZone();
newStart.DateTime= "2016-08-06T19:00:00.0000000";
newStart.TimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";

DateTimeTimeZone newEnd = new DateTimeTimeZone();
newEnd.DateTime = "2016-08-06T19:30:00.0000000";
newEnd.TimeZone = "Asia/Kolkata";
```